# React PWA IOS/Safari click event on file input sometimes not opening menu

Tags: ios, file-upload, safari, onclick, progressive-web-apps

we have a problem with our React PWA app and I need the swarm intelligence.

The following issue occurres with some of our iOS 15 users starting ~October 2021:

The users click (touch) an `<input type=file`-Button and no OS menu opens to select "Take a photo", "Select file" etc. However, this only happens very irregularly and there is still no recognizable pattern depending on the iOS version or device model. The function worked for many users for a long time without any issues.

We know that common issues with iOS when the OnRelease event happens outside of the button area. However, from our opinion we are talking about another issue.

In last days we have received multiple reports of this issue including videos showing this bug. But we are not able to recreate this ourselves. In those videos you see someone is clicking on the button (the button color changes), but the menu does not open.

We initially used the classic `<input type=file>`  and styled this with CSS. Now we read about some best practices and added an additional button which triggers the .click() of the input.

I found a similar StackOverflow article: [React PWA Image Upload in Mobile Safari breaks application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299227/react-pwa-image-upload-in-mobile-safari-breaks-application)

> It seems that the only ways to reset the PWA context are to restart the phone, delete the app and re-add it to the home screen, or to open an external link

That's exactly our workaround we are using: deleting the app icon and re-add the app to the start screen is the only solution to get the issue resolved. As the code works before and afterwards I don't think that our code is wrong. It just happend after some unknown time/event/occurence for different users.

Does anyone have any idea or direction to take a look?

I've just checked the webkit issue tracker but not found something matching. The issue not exists on Android or Windows based devices.

Best Regards

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with a PWA app using Uppy which renders the file input and a <button> with onClick handler that apparently stops working when certain things happend.

Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Not really... We still use the described .click() method, but the issue didn't occurs within last 3 months. A few days ago I've got a user report that it's back. But it guess it was a single user with outdated iOS version.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue, and it seems that a consistent way to make it appear is to open the app, use the file input field and then click away from the app and then back. I.e. show the home screen and then the app again, without actually "swiping the app away".